Wordpress ACF update_post_meta not writing when i pass the post id as a variable
When a users submits a CF7 form I have a function hook that fires and does the saving to a custom template for the current form.  However I want to update one field of another already existing custom post type (all created using acf).
I know the target post id as this is passed as a hidden field on the displayed form but this doesn't work
$postfield = 'post_status';
$newvalue = 'Submitted';
update_post_meta( $postid, $postfield, $newvalue);
......but this does?
update_post_meta( 2147, $postfield, $newvalue);
If i pass the post id as a raw integer it works fine but if i try to pass it as a variable it just won't write the update.
I've trawled posts and tried suggestions but can't seem to find a fix.  I have tried togling the REST Api on and off for the ACF fields, I have the target field set as a numeric and even tried forcing it to (int) before passing it just to be certain.  Feel like I must be missing something really simple!

update_post_meta() returns false if it fails. One reason for it to fail is if absint( $post_id ) returns false, that is if $post_id isn't an int or a string containing an int. Double check the value you're passing? Check for a return of false?

Thanks O.  I've doubled back and checked the postid is saved as a numeric and i've passed it as an absint and still no joy.  Also using update_field gives me the same result so at this point i'm thinking something between CF7 & ACF isn't quite gelling.

Ok so after a lot of frustration I got this to work BUT as for why it works I'm a little vague.
My parent post ID was saved as a numeric in the child post. The child post is editable by the user who fills out a cf7 form and submits it.  On submit a hook is fired and data is saved etc.  The aim was to also have a single field in the parent post (in the backend) update to register that the user has submitted the form by changing the value of a status field.
My child form loads the post date into an array using
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
$data = $submission->get_posted_data();

Then I assign and access the elements with ;
$parentid= $data['parentid']; //as parentid is saved to the child post

This for some reason does not want to pass the id to the variable (even though for every other variable i have it works just fine.
instead I have to directly assign the parentid variable outside of the array using;
$parentid = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'parentid', true );
$postfield = 'post_status';
$newvalue = 'new status setting';
update_post_meta($parentid, $postfield, $newvalue);

it works but i would still like to know why and what was going wrong?
it feels like i'm missing something very simple trying to add 2+2 but instead having to do 1+1+1+1!
